# How can i modify a command in MINIX 3.2.1 so that uses my own system call?

Tags: fileserver, minix, rmdir, netbsd

Good evening you all!

I'm doing homework on **minix 3.2.1**, where i'm asked to create an new system call, 
**my_rmdir**, that acts exactly like **rmdir** but also prints the name of the deleted directory. Also I'm supposed to modify the system's source code so when i give the **rmdir** command then instead of calling the **do_rmdir** function the system should call my own **do_myrmdir** function.

In the past, I have done the same homework with the **mkdir** command but there everything was simple because **mkdir** was properly declared minix style and I made changes to

```
/usr/src/servers/vfs/proto.h
/usr/src/servers/vfs/open.c
/usr/src/servers/vfs/request.c
/usr/src/servers/vfs/table.c
/usr/include/minix/callnr.h
```

and everything worked allright. But now, I think because of the **NETBSD code infusion**, I'm a bit lost.

Also the point isn't creating a new system call from scratch because first i don't have the knowledge and second the change i need to make is very small.
The number one problem i have is that i can't find where the original **do_rmdir** is declared and how it is connected with the **rmdir** command.

In the **/usr/src/servers/vfs/table.c** file line 58

```
do_unlink,  /* 40 = rmdir   */
```

makes it more confusing

Any help or ideas?

If you need further information please ask.

*I'm new to the forum, i tried to ask properly, thanks for your understanding.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got it!

The **rmdir** command calls the **do_unlink** function and based on what the user rights are, it requests either the **rmdir** or **unlink** command. The difference is that **unlink** can do some dangerous things so it's only for admin use.